Flutter is not waiting for a await function to be completed before going to next line
can anyone help me understand why flutter is skipping the await part of my code and triggres it a bit late?
I can try a diffrent way to achieve this goal but I want to learn why after calling the CheckAuth(), it returns false first on the onPressed and then after a few sec it prints print("Signed in").
Future<bool> CheckAuth(context, userTypedVerificationCode) async {
  bool signedIn = false;
  String phoneNumberString = "+${getUserPhoneNumber()}";
  await FirebaseAuth.instance.verifyPhoneNumber(
    phoneNumber: phoneNumberString,
    codeSent: (String verificationId, int? resendToken) async {
     
      PhoneAuthCredential credential = PhoneAuthProvider.credential(
          verificationId: verificationId, smsCode: userTypedVerificationCode);

      
      await auth.signInWithCredential(credential);

      if (auth.currentUser?.uid != null) {
        print("Signed in");
        setUid(auth.currentUser!.uid);
        signedIn = true;
      } else {
        signedIn = false;
      }
    },
    
  );

  if (signedIn) {
    return Future.value(true);
  } else {
    return Future.value(false);
  }
}

onPressed: () async {
  bool isSignedIn = await CheckAuth(context, currentText);

  if (isSignedIn) {
    Navigator.pushNamed(context, ProfilePage1Screen.id);
    
  } else {
    
  }

I expected the code to wait for auth.signInWithCredential(credential) to be completed before returning a value for CheckAuth()

Illogical, code seems ok except the navigation part.

well in this section I see the documentation is using the async for codesent: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/flutter/phone-auth#codesent

The point is that verifyPhoneNumber cannot determine when codeSent completes.  verifyPhoneNumber's returned Future therefore must complete independently of the completion of the codeSent callback.  If you want to wait for the codeSent callback to finish, it probably should use a Completer, and then CheckAuth should await that Completer's Future.
